# How to prevent showing on OS toolbar and disable buttons on App Info on Lollipop

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin app via .NET running on custom restricted Lollipop.

I want to know if it is disable the scenarios below

1 Make it not appear on the OS toolbar (the bar that slides down from the top when users swipe down)

2 disable display of App info for the app

3 disable all buttons on App Info page.

Toolbar: 
Make the app not appear on the OS toolbar below
[image: Toolbar]

App Info

2 disable display of App Info for the app

3 disable all buttons on App Info page.

[image: App info]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT based on understanding that it's not a custom Android dist.

1. Lollipop introduced something called single-purpose devices which a couple of options for locking your app into the foreground (app pinning and lock task mode). You can read about it here:
   https://developer.android.com/work/cosu
2. If you keep your app locked per (1), the user can't get to settings. Other than that, there's what Device Policy Manager offers. For example, a DPM app can set other apps as uninstallable:
   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setUninstallBlocked(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean). It's a large topic. I didn't immediately see anything that would prevent them from getting into Settings for your app. I'd suggest you explore that topic on your own though.

Comment: I am not building the OS myself. So I cannot change it via coding from my application?